# R:Time dependent parameters in a differential equations model

Tags: r, differential-equations

I have a differential equations model (see below), I am looking for some way to change some of the values of the parameters at a certain time step or at a certain value of one of the state variables (or another way if it works better). For example, I would like to change GammaQR and GammaQD from 0 to .02 at time step 5 (or possibly, if it works better, when H > .04). I have no clue how to go about this and would really appreciate any advice! Thanks!

```
 VS  = 0.01    
VE  = 0.01  
VH  = 0.01  
BSE = 10 #
BSI = 10  #
THE = 1/10      
TEI =  1/3 
DeltaID = .5 
GammaIR = .5 
XIQ = 0.001  
XEQ = 0.01 
XHQ = 0.05 
GammaQR = .02  
GammaQD = .02 

library(deSolve)

pars <- c(VS, VE, VH, BSE, BSI, THE, TEI, DeltaID, GammaIR, XIQ, XEQ, XHQ, GammaQR)

init.values <- c(S = .99 , H = .01 , E = 0 , V = 0, I = 0 , Q = 0 , D = 0 , R = 0 )

times <- seq(0, 60, by = 1)

Smallpox <- function(time, y.values, parameters){
   with(as.list(c(y.values, parameters)), {

    dS.dt = -VS*S - BSI*S*I - BSE*E*S 
    dH.dt = BSI*S*I + BSE*E*S  - THE*H - XHQ*H - VH*H 
    dE.dt = THE*H - XEQ*E - VE*E - DeltaID*E - TEI*E
    dV.dt = VS*S + VE*E + VH*H
    dI.dt = TEI*E - XIQ*I - GammaIR*I - DeltaID*I
    dQ.dt = XHQ*H + XIQ*I + XEQ*E - GammaQR*Q - GammaQD*Q
    dD.dt = DeltaID*I + DeltaID*E + GammaQD*Q
    dR.dt = GammaQR*Q + DeltaID*I


    return(list(c(dS.dt, dH.dt, dE.dt, dV.dt, dI.dt, dQ.dt, dD.dt, dR.dt)))
  })
}

out <- as.data.frame(ode(func = Smallpox, y = init.values, parms = pars, times = times))
tail(out)

matplot(out$time, out[ ,2:9], type = "l", xlab = "time", ylab = "percent of       population", main = "Model Name", lwd = 2, col = c("black", "red", "green", "Blue", "cyan", "purple", "grey", "magenta"), lty = 1:8)
```

Comment: see `?events` in the `deSolve` package.

Comment: If you know how long your time sequence is, it could be as simple as setting, e.g., `GammaQR<-c(rep(0,5),rep(0.2,55))` and doing vectorized operations.